# Couchbase for NLog

Tags: .net, nlog, couchbase

I am new to Couchbase and NoSql, so I am wondering if using Couchbase as a target for NLog logging is viable.  I wrote a quick and dirty Couchbase/NLog target which does log the information in the specified bucket. So writing to the CB is done and working.

The problem I see is getting/reading the data from the bucket. I don't know the key names... they are just random guids. I just want a dump of the data and CB 1.8 doesn't support getting all of the keys from the .NET client.

So if I want to make an viewer app to view the data in the bucket, where do I start?

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't an option. You have to have the Key name to get the value out of the cache.

Comment: Couchbase 2.0 supports map/reduce views and you could easily use those views to query the results.  Checkout the Couchbase Labs ELMAH provider for Couchbase - https://github.com/couchbaselabs/elmah-couchbase.  It accomplishes something similar.  If there's anything I can do to help out, let me know.  An NLog target for Couchbase would be great to have!

Answer (score 2):

You have to store every key and its metadata in ram.  I doubt you want to do that for logs.

You might want to store in ElasticSearch instead.  There is a .net client called Nest, or you can just do json posts.  Elasticsearch does not have that 1:1 relationship between documents and ram.

Comment: I agree on elasticsearch completely, BUT couchbase can expire documents, so you can easily manage a reasonable amount of logs if your retention time is short.

Answer (score 1):

Using a map reduce view you could get a list of all keys by using doc.key like below, or if you want the key (id) and the full document then just emit doc. This is only possible in couchbase 2.0 and above.

```
function (doc, meta) {
 if(meta.type == 'json') {
   emit(doc.key, null);    
 }
}
```

You could use the cbbackup tool to dump all the data visit http://www.couchbase.com/docs//couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-backup-restore-backup-cbbackup.html

Couchbase also supports replicating data to an elastic search node/cluster using XDCR in the admin console. Visit http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-elastic-search/

Answer (score 0):

With Couchbase Server 3.x you can now eject metadata and document data from RAM. This feature allows Couchbase Server 3 to store extremely large data sets and allow you the ability to incrementally index the updates in RAM, even on large or high-velocity data sets.

Additionally, as others have pointed out, Couchbase server has plugins for Lucidworks Solr, ElasticSearch, Splunk, and more.

Give Couchbase 3.0 a try and see for yourself!

http://www.couchbase.com/nosql-databases/downloads